# Greatest number in a column using shell script

Tags: linux, shell-script

I have a file that contains some data in column format, for example:

```
219m
219m
3.9g
3.9g
4.0g
4.0g
4.1g
4.1g
4.2g
4.2g
4.2g
```

I want to compare the data and find the greatest value of these. Here g stands for GB and m stands for MB. How would I find the greatest number using a Linux shell script?

Comment: you can take a look at the `units` man page.

Answer (score 6):

`sort -h` can do this for you, but it needs the magnitude suffix (i.e. 'g' and 'm') to be in capitals.  So for your data, you could do

```
tr a-z A-Z < filename | sort -h
```

---

In some locales, the `.` is not recognized as the decimal separator (see [Decimal separator: Examples of use [Wikipedia]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator#Examples_of_use)). If that is the case, modify the command as e.g.:

```
tr a-z A-Z < filename | LC_NUMERIC=C sort -h
```

Comment: This actually does not work in this case (at least not better than regular `sort` or `sort -n`). I guess it's the decimal separator that confuses `sort -h`.

Comment: Sorry, yes it was the decimal separator, but changing locale fixed that. I made a mistake when I first tested this, since I only changed `LANG` on the machine, where `LC_NUMERIC` was also set to override. It might be good information to include in the answer. `tr a-z A-Z < filename | LC_NUMERIC=C sort -h` fixes things if the user is in an area where `.` is not the native decimal separator.

Comment: Good spot -- I never would have thought of that!

Comment: Related: [List of countries by decimal separator used](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator#Examples_of_use). Being part of the first row in that table made this an easy (inevitable, even) find for me! :-D (I downvoted this answer since it didn't seem to work before I found that the problem was local, and SU won't let me change the vote unless the post is edited, so I'll do that).